# "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

For all below print statements I'm receiving "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" error.

I believe the tags is a dictionary but not really sure, this is an output from a different function.

```
tags = [{'Key': 'Application Owner', 'Value': 'Test123'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'TESTSERVER'}, {'Key': 'Application', 'Value': 'Data Analytics'}, {'Key': 'Email Contact', 'Value': 'test.123@example.com'}]

server_name = tags[1]['Value']
print(server_name)
if tags['Key'] == 'Name':
    instancename = tags["Value"]
print(instancename)
for i in tags:
    if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
       name = tags["Value"]
print(name)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `tags` is a list. That's what the square brackets indicate.

Comment: You are not getting errors on your print statements; please copy and paste the actual errors.

Comment: The error doe snot come from the print statement itself, but from the addressing of the tags list. You are trying to address it with a key ("Value") instead of an indice like 0 or 1

Comment: Thank you for the explanation guys, below answer gave the output I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because the type of tags is list.

I modified your code.

```
tags = [{'Key': 'Application Owner', 'Value': 'Test123'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'TESTSERVER'},
        {'Key': 'Application', 'Value': 'Data Analytics'}, {'Key': 'Email Contact', 'Value': 'test.123@example.com'}]

for tag in tags:
    if tag["Key"] == 'Name':
        name = tag["Value"]
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```
server_name = tags[1]['Value']
print(server_name)
if tags[1]['Key'] == 'Name':
    instancename = tags[1]["Value"]  # look at specific (2nd) tag same as above
print(instancename)
for tag in tags:  # i renamed to tag
    if tag["Key"] == 'Name':  # dictionary is tag, not tags
       name = tag["Value"]  # dictionary is tag, not tags
print(name)
```